# How can i merge three ordered arrays in one ordered array? In O(n)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

My code should pick three arrays and return a combination of the three, the arrays can have different length. The code should do the combination in O(n).

> Example: a[] = {1,2} b[] = {1,4,5} c[] = {2,4,5,6}
>
> My result should be: d[] = {1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,6}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to create one array temp to merge (a,b) and other array to merge (temp,c) but every merge will be O(n). So my code is currently running in O(n²) i think.

Comment: Not quite, remember that `O(n)` + `O(n)` is **still** `O(n)`!

Comment: I think i gotcha then! :) Thanks Glains!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach (and I am sure there are many others) would be:

Create the output array based on the sum of the input array lengths:

```
int[] output = new int[a.length + b.length + c.length];
```

Create an index pointer for each of the input arrays:

```
int aIndex = 0;
int bIndex = 0;
int cIndex = 0;
```

Loop once for each position in the output array, and fill it with the lowest value at the current index of each input array (checking that we haven't used that array up):

```
for(int outputIndex = 0; outputIndex < output.length; outputIndex++) {
    if (aIndex < a.length
            && (bIndex >= b.length || a[aIndex] <= b[bIndex])
            && (cIndex >= c.length || a[aIndex] <= c[cIndex])) {
        output[outputIndex] = a[aIndex];
        aIndex++;
    } else if (bIndex < b.length
            && (aIndex >= a.length || b[bIndex] <= a[aIndex])
            && (cIndex >= c.length || b[bIndex] <= c[cIndex])) {
        output[outputIndex] = b[bIndex];
        bIndex++;
    } else {
        output[outputIndex] =  c[cIndex];
        cIndex++;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here's my compiled and tested code:

```
public class Join {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2};
        int[] b = {1, 4, 5};
        int[] c = {2, 4, 5, 6};

        int[] output = new int[a.length + b.length + c.length];

        int aIndex = 0;
        int bIndex = 0;
        int cIndex = 0;

        for(int outputIndex = 0; outputIndex < output.length; outputIndex++) {
            if (aIndex < a.length
                    && (bIndex >= b.length || a[aIndex] <= b[bIndex])
                    && (cIndex >= c.length || a[aIndex] <= c[cIndex])) {
                output[outputIndex] = a[aIndex];
                aIndex++;
            } else if (bIndex < b.length
                    && (aIndex >= a.length || b[bIndex] <= a[aIndex])
                    && (cIndex >= c.length || b[bIndex] <= c[cIndex])) {
                output[outputIndex] = b[bIndex];
                bIndex++;
            } else {
                output[outputIndex] =  c[cIndex];
                cIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Verified in debugger with a breakpoint at the end of the method.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I think its a better implementation than mine! I created two arrays: one temp to recieve the merge(a,b) and another one to recive merge (temp,c). As Glains said my code O(n) + O(n) is still O(n), so i gotcha!

Comment: That depends upon the priorities of your non-functional requirements. Unless otherwise specified, aim for clarity of code (simplicity). One of the largest costs in software engineering is maintenance. I'm not completely happy with my complex `if` statements. Personally, I would try to refactor them into something simpler. If your code is clearer than mine, it will probably be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

*[Answered before O(n) constraint added in question edit.]*

Add all arrays to list and sort again. An example would be:

```
Integer[] a = {1, 2};
Integer[] b = {1, 4, 5};
Integer[] c = {2, 4, 5, 6};

List<Integer> lists = new ArrayList<>();
lists.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
lists.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
lists.addAll(Arrays.asList(c));

//print
lists
  .stream()
  .sorted()
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Agreed @Andy. I didn’t saw that as the question edited and complexity part added later. My code complexity is O(n log n) as adding to arraylist is O(1) but sorted function complexity is O(n log n). The selected answer is correct one. Thanks